# How to make a python array into a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a 1 dimensional array...

```
myArray = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

How to make this into a np.array?

Comment: `myArray` isn't an array, it is a Python set.

Comment: EDIT: Oh it is a set. Thanks!

Comment: But what type is `myArray `then?

Comment: Btw you could convert your `set` to `list` with `list(myArray)` and then pass that to `np.array` to make numpy array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, what you have is not an array, but a `set`. You can create an numpy array from a `set` if you want, but that probably won't be quite what you want (sets are arbitrarily ordered). I'd strongly recommend starting with a `list` instead by using square brackets:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Then you can turn it into a numpy array by calling an appropriate numpy function:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array(my_list)
```

You may also want to specify a `dtype` to the numpy array constructor, as otherwise it may default to something you don't want (such as `int` rather than `float`, or visa versa).

Comment: Thanks a lot Blckknght!